# How to not lose the css while appending html to an element?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using bootstrap chosen to render dropdown menu.When I use the following code the rendering works fine.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country" class="chosen-select chosenContainer" tabindex="2">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="United States">United States</option>
                        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                        <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Problem occurs when I append the above code to a div ,all the css is lost and a ordinary dropdown menu is displayed.

```
    function populate()
{
    var str="   <div class=\"row\">\n" +
"                <div class=\"col-lg-3\" " +
"                    <select data-placeholder=\"Choose a Country\" class=\"chosen-select chosenContainers\" tabindex=\"2\">\n" +
"                        <option value=\"\"></option>\n" +
"                        <option value=\"United States\">United States</option>\n" +
"                        <option value=\"United Kingdom\">United Kingdom</option>\n" +
"                        <option value=\"Afghanistan\">Afghanistan</option>\n" +
"                        <option value=\"Albania\">Albania</option>\n" +
"                        <option value=\"Algeria\">Algeria</option>\n" +
"                        <option value=\"American Samoa\">American Samoa</option>\n" +
"\n" +
"                    </select>\n" +
"                </div>\n" +
"            </div>";

var elementDiv=document.getElementById("dynamicTag");
$("#dynamicTag").append(str);


}
```

[image]

How to not lose the css while appending html to an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the html you write is correct ?

there's a missing closing > here :

```
"                <div class=\"col-lg-3\" " +
```

Also you might want to write like this instead :

```
'<div class="col-lg-3"> '
```

You don't have to escape double quotes if they are inside single quotes (and vice-versa)

Comment: The same html is working above,but not when appended to a html element.And yes even single quotes are not working.

Comment: Maybe you need to re-do the $('.chosen-select').chosen();

Comment: $('.chosen-select').chosen(); is already defined .Do I need to invoke it again after appending .

Comment: re-do the $('.chosen-select').chosen(); is the answer.Thanks.Could you explain what has happened.

Comment: $('.chosen-select').chosen() is selecting all the elements of your page with a class 'chosen-select' and transform them to make them look like the special chosen dropdown. So when a new element is added to the DOM, it needs to be transform as well. What makes the dropdown look nice is not only the css but also some javascript applied to it.